# Setting public IP on nested VM inside google instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud VM instance and i am running another VM inside this, What i want is to give 5 interface to nested VM and provide them with public ip(external ip). Is that possible and if yes then can someone please tell me how to do it?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately it's not possible at the moment to provide external IP to the nested VM*. To find more details please have a look at the documentation [Enabling nested virtualization for VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances).

**To provide access to the nested VM from outside the host VM** follow instructions at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#configuring_a_nested_vm_to_be_accessible_from_outside_the_host_vm):

> You can set up an instance with multiple network interfaces or set up
> an instance using an [alias IP](http://alias%20IP) so that VMs outside the host VM can
> ping the nested VM.
>
> The following sample procedure sets up your host and nested VM so that
> the nested VM is accessible from other VMs on the same network using
> alias IPs. This procedure uses an imaginary subnet called subnet1 that
> was previously [created](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-alias-ip-ranges). You can replace `subnet1` with the name of your
> own subnet, or create a new subnet called `subnet1`.

Comment: Hello @UPENDRABARTWAL and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!